# Baggage carousel for checked-in luggage tagged outside EU at Manises/Valencia Airport

Tags: luggage, india, eu, valencia

Soon I will be travelling from New Delhi, India (non-EU) to Valencia, Spain (Schengen + EU). As there are no direct flights, I will be connecting either through Frankfurt, Germany (Via Lufthansa) or Paris, France (Via Air France).

I have read that they have a different baggage carousel for checked-in luggage tagged outside the EU, which often leads to delay or misplaced baggage [(For reference jump to 1:17)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIjifOonKMU). I don't speak Spanish (learning), and by the time I reach Valencia, I will be exhausted due to a day-long journey; therefore, I am a little worried about finding my way through the airport.

Does anyone have any experience of arrivals at Manises/Valencia Airport from a non-EU country? It will be conducive if someone can share their experience?

Comment: Where have you read that? AFAIK such separate baggage carousels do not exist.

Comment: I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIjifOonKMU) arrival guide video on youtube, and at 1:17, he mentions the different baggage carousels for checked-in luggage tagged outside the EU.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that they do that because no luggage handler is going to bother with sorting tags during loading or unloading. They sort by destination and that's it. What I think that's causing the confusion is that Valencia has 2 terminals, but only Terminal 1 (arrivals) has luggage services [(source)](https://www.airport-valencia.com/es/terminales-1-2-aeropuerto-valencia.php). Terminal 2 is departures only

Comment: Not only this doesn't happen, there's no reason for it to happen. You self declare by leaving at the correct colored customs exit -- it's typically blue for arrival from within EU, green for nothing to declare and red for items to declare. Policing the carousels instead would be a huge and pointless task.

Comment: Since your luggage will have originated outside of the EU it will not have green tags, custom officers will notice that, and might call you over for an inspection. But it does not require luggage with white tags to be kept separate...

Comment: In any case, your Spanish doesn't matter. In airports you have signage also in English, and most staff (nearly all of client-side staff) can speak English.

Comment: [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHvQlkC5pnU&t=13s) Even if there is a cut in the video it looks like there are carousels without customs. [The airport website](https://www.aena.es/en/valencia/servicis-de-l-aeroport/categories/arrivals-area.html) also mentions a "non-EU baggage reclaim hall".

Comment: @Anders what I did find out is that flights coming from outside the EU do indeed use different luggage carousels. But no indication that luggage from flights originating inside the EU would be sorted according to the colour of the tag and send to different carousels. That is not something I have ever seen done at an airport in Europe.

Comment: @KristvanBesien I haven't seen it either but question is about Valencia airport only. If a passenger arrives via transit to the carousels without customs how is he/she supposed to choose red channel? The airport might have chosen a solution with a different carousel for non-EU luggage to avoid rebuilding the airport.